# Only Display Wordpress Posts with Specific Custom Field Value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display posts on a Wordpress page with a custom field value of 'in-stock' and custom field key name of '_status'.

How do I add a line of code below that selects posts with custom field value of 'in-stock' for the custom field called '_status'?

```
    global $wp_query;

    $wp_query->set("orderby",'meta_value_num');
    $wp_query->set("meta_key",'inventory_number');
    $wp_query->set("order",'desc');
    $wp_query->set("category_name",'tape');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the global `$wp_query` object like that. That's why the `pre_get_posts` hook exists. Then you can set a custom `meta_query`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts($query)
{
  if ($query->is_main_query()) {

    $query->set('meta_query', array(array(
      'key' => '_status',
      'value' => 'in-stock',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask why this is better? And also, what does the compare part do? This worked great.

Comment: Take a look here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts, and here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.

Comment: Also I'm getting "Not Found" when trying to use the same code on a page but changing the value to "out-of-stock". Does the global query not work on pages?

Comment: On a page I would use a new `WP_query`. The `pre_get_posts` works best for modifying the main query.